# RSA with padding chance of collision on same input

Tags: java, rsa

I am relying on the fact that the RSA signature of some input is going to be unique every time (even when provided the same value).

Given I'm not cryptography expert, I am questioning my decision. What is the chance of two RSA signatures on the same value to be the same?

I am using Java if that matters.

Comment: This is dependent on additional details of the signature algorithm including the hash function and the padding scheme. The most common padding scheme is PKCS1 ver 1.5 type 1 padding. This padding is completely deterministic, and the same data always results in the same signature for a given RSA key. The modern RSA signing scheme defined in PKCS1 ver 2 is RSA-PSS. That scheme does incorporates a random component, so no two signatures should ever be the same. Support for it varies. RSA-PSS is not supported in Java 8, but is supported in Java 11 as "RSASSA-PSS".